# XML reader for my big files

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for big XML reader, I tried XML Copy Editor, but it can't handle the big xml files (20-50MB) I have. I don't want to edit the XML, only browsing that.

Comment: I have yet to find a GUI xml editor quicker than xml copy editor so my answer is solely based on command line ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML Copy editor (like most of the similar programs) try to read in the XML in 1 go. Depending on the formatting of the XML this might take some time. What you are looking for is `byte-stream` editor (these load only part of the file before showing you it).

- If it is just browsing a file the command line `less` might be interesting.

> [Less](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/less) is a program similar to more, but which allows backward  movement in the file as well as forward movement. Also, less does not have to read the entire input file before  starting,  so  with  large  input files  it  starts  up  faster than text editors.

- And there is also good old reliable `sed`

> [Sed](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/sed) is a stream editor. A stream editor is used to perform basic text transformations on an input stream (a file or input from  a  pipeline). While  in  some  ways similar to an editor which permits scripted edits (such as ed), sed works by making only one pass over the input(s),  and is consequently more efficient.  But it is sed's ability to filter text in a pipeline which particularly distinguishes it from other  types  of editors.